# How to judge an iOS app whether a 32 bit app?

Tags: ios

I heard iOS11 will not support 32 bit app so I wonder whether my app is 32 bit app.Any way I can do?

Comment: don't you have the source code of your app?

Comment: @KirthikaVijayakumar  yeah I have,then what should I do?

Comment: Download the iOS 11 beta and run the app. It will tell you if it’s not supported.

Answer (score 0):

See Architecture settings in your build settings as in the below pic

[image]

Comment: what should we be looking for? Does including armv7 means app supports 32bit or app is 32bit.

Comment: You should add armv7 and arm64 to support IOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

If the Architecture under your app's 'Build Setting' in XCode is "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" Then its 32 bit. You can modify to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) i.e. (armv7,arm64) and make it available on iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
First, try unzip the ipa file to a directory, eg:

unzip <filename>.ipa -d ~/Downloads/tmp
Second, use file command to identify the architectures, eg:

file ~/Downloads/tmp/Payload/<appname>.app/<appname>
```

Yow will see the output like "Mach-O 64-bit executable" or "Mach-O 32-bit executable"